# Programmatically create a ajax field

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

I'm creating a custom field in my Drupal 8 installation in which you can select brand and model of some cars.

So if I select Audi from a select list, the next select list will make you select only Audi models.

It's the same appereance of the "Hierarchical select" module, but I cannot use taxonomy and my data is taken from fields of nodes

The problem is, there is something wrong

I have my formElement function where i create the widgets

```
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $marche=$modelli=$alimentazioni=array();
    $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('marche');
    foreach($terms as $term)
        $marche[$term->tid]=$term->name;

    $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('modelli');
    foreach($terms as $term)
        $modelli[$term->tid]=$term->name;

    $terms = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('alimentazioni');
    foreach($terms as $term)
        $alimentazioni[$term->tid]=$term->name;

    $element['usato_marca'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Marca'),
      '#options' => $marche,
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxHandlerMarca'],
        'wrapper' => 'usato_modelli_ajax',
        'event' => 'change',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'progress' => array(
            'type' => 'throbber',
            'message' => NULL,
        )
    )
    );

    $element['usato_modello'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Modello'),
      '#options' => $modelli,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="usato_modelli_ajax">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );

    $element['usato_alimentazione'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Alimentazione'),
      '#options' => $alimentazioni
    );


    $element += [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
    ];

    return array('value' => $element);
  }
```

and the callback function

```
public function ajaxHandlerMarca(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form = $form_state->getCompleteForm();
        return $form['usato_modello'];
    }
```

The ajax is triggered from the first select, but it always gives the error "Undefined index: usato_modello", but there is, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know much about ajax, but I compared your code to some similar code I wrote. Is "replace" a valid value for your "method"? I didn't include  the method, and it seems the default is "replaceWith". On the Ajax API page (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x), there's a link to the valid options for method, and "replace" isn't listed. Otherwise, I can't spot any other issues... Have you tried printing the array_keys for $form in your callback function? Perhaps that would help.

Comment: One more thought: is this a subform? If so, take a look at this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239179/ajax-forms-will-break-when-used-in-subform